# Unnaturally large Postgres database size

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm not very experienced with Postgres but I have a relatively small database (less than ~300 rows total) but it takes up more than 150 MB of storage. It grew to this from ~11 MB without much addition of new data. I was wondering what might be the cause of this and how can I fix this issue?

I ran the following queries to get an understanding of what might be happening, but being new to Postgres I cannot really find a proper fix.

```sql
SELECT SUM(pg_database_size(pg_database.datname)) / (1024 * 1024) as size_mb 
FROM pg_database;
```

```
| size_mb              |
| -------------------- |
| 162.0249948501586914 |
```

```sql
select table_schema, table_name, 
       pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"'||table_schema||'"."'||table_name||'"')) as size
from information_schema.tables;
```

The result:

`pg_class` and `pg_statistic` take up 95 MB and 43 MB respectively.

```
| table_schema       | table_name                            | size       |
| ------------------ | ------------------------------------- | ---------- |
| pg_catalog         | pg_statistic                          | 43 MB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_type                               | 208 kB     |
| pg_catalog         | pg_foreign_table                      | 16 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_authid                             | 80 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_shadow                             | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_statistic_ext_data                 | 16 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_roles                              | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_settings                           | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_file_settings                      | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_hba_file_rules                     | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_config                             | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_shmem_allocations                  | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_prepared_statements                | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_largeobject                        | 8192 bytes |
| pg_catalog         | pg_user_mapping                       | 24 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_progress_vacuum               | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_replication_origin_status          | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_subscription                       | 24 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_attribute                          | 848 kB     |
| pg_catalog         | pg_proc                               | 1216 kB    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_class                              | 95 MB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_attrdef                            | 80 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_constraint                         | 136 kB     |
| pg_catalog         | pg_inherits                           | 16 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_index                              | 112 kB     |
| pg_catalog         | pg_operator                           | 232 kB     |
| pg_catalog         | pg_opfamily                           | 80 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_opclass                            | 80 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_am                                 | 72 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_amop                               | 192 kB     |
| pg_catalog         | pg_amproc                             | 128 kB     |
| pg_catalog         | pg_language                           | 80 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_largeobject_metadata               | 8192 bytes |
| pg_catalog         | pg_aggregate                          | 72 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_statistic_ext                      | 32 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_rewrite                            | 696 kB     |
| pg_catalog         | pg_trigger                            | 96 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_event_trigger                      | 48 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_description                        | 496 kB     |
| pg_catalog         | pg_cast                               | 80 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_progress_cluster              | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_progress_create_index         | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_progress_basebackup           | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_user_mappings                      | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_enum                               | 56 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_namespace                          | 80 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_conversion                         | 96 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_depend                             | 1240 kB    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_database                           | 80 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_db_role_setting                    | 32 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_tablespace                         | 80 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_auth_members                       | 72 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_shdepend                           | 112 kB     |
| pg_catalog         | pg_shdescription                      | 64 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_ts_config                          | 72 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_ts_config_map                      | 88 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_ts_dict                            | 80 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_ts_parser                          | 72 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_ts_template                        | 72 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_extension                          | 80 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_foreign_data_wrapper               | 24 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_foreign_server                     | 24 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_policy                             | 48 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_replication_origin                 | 24 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_default_acl                        | 48 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_init_privs                         | 72 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_seclabel                           | 16 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_shseclabel                         | 16 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_collation                          | 80 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_partitioned_table                  | 16 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_range                              | 56 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_transform                          | 16 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_sequence                           | 24 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_publication                        | 40 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_publication_rel                    | 16 kB      |
| pg_catalog         | pg_subscription_rel                   | 8192 bytes |
| pg_catalog         | pg_group                              | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_user                               | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_policies                           | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_rules                              | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_views                              | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_tables                             | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_matviews                           | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_indexes                            | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_sequences                          | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stats                              | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stats_ext                          | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_publication_tables                 | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_locks                              | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_cursors                            | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_available_extensions               | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_available_extension_versions       | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_prepared_xacts                     | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_seclabels                          | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_statio_user_tables                 | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_all_indexes                   | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_timezone_abbrevs                   | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_timezone_names                     | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_sys_indexes                   | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_all_tables                    | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_xact_all_tables               | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_sys_tables                    | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_xact_sys_tables               | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_user_tables                   | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_xact_user_tables              | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_statio_all_tables                  | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_statio_sys_tables                  | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_user_indexes                  | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_statio_all_indexes                 | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_statio_sys_indexes                 | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_statio_user_indexes                | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_statio_all_sequences               | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_statio_sys_sequences               | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_statio_user_sequences              | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_activity                      | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_replication                   | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_slru                          | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_wal_receiver                  | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_subscription                  | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_ssl                           | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_gssapi                        | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_replication_slots                  | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_database                      | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_database_conflicts            | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_user_functions                | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_xact_user_functions           | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_archiver                      | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_bgwriter                      | 0 bytes    |
| pg_catalog         | pg_stat_progress_analyze              | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | columns                               | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | information_schema_catalog_name       | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | collations                            | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | applicable_roles                      | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | administrable_role_authorizations     | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | column_privileges                     | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | attributes                            | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | collation_character_set_applicability | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | character_sets                        | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | check_constraint_routine_usage        | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | check_constraints                     | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | column_column_usage                   | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | column_domain_usage                   | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | column_udt_usage                      | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | constraint_column_usage               | 0 bytes    |
| extensions         | pg_stat_statements                    | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | constraint_table_usage                | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | domain_constraints                    | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | domain_udt_usage                      | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | domains                               | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | enabled_roles                         | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | sql_implementation_info               | 48 kB      |
| information_schema | key_column_usage                      | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | parameters                            | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | referential_constraints               | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | role_column_grants                    | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | sql_parts                             | 48 kB      |
| information_schema | routine_privileges                    | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | role_routine_grants                   | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | routines                              | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | schemata                              | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | tables                                | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | sequences                             | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | sql_sizing                            | 48 kB      |
| information_schema | sql_features                          | 104 kB     |
| information_schema | table_constraints                     | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | transforms                            | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | table_privileges                      | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | role_table_grants                     | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | udt_privileges                        | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | triggered_update_columns              | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | triggers                              | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | usage_privileges                      | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | role_udt_grants                       | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | role_usage_grants                     | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | user_defined_types                    | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | view_column_usage                     | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | view_routine_usage                    | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | view_table_usage                      | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | foreign_tables                        | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | views                                 | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | data_type_privileges                  | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | _pg_user_mappings                     | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | element_types                         | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | _pg_foreign_table_columns             | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | column_options                        | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | _pg_foreign_data_wrappers             | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | foreign_data_wrapper_options          | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | user_mapping_options                  | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | foreign_data_wrappers                 | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | _pg_foreign_servers                   | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | foreign_server_options                | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | foreign_servers                       | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | _pg_foreign_tables                    | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | user_mappings                         | 0 bytes    |
| information_schema | foreign_table_options                 | 0 bytes    |
| auth               | refresh_tokens                        | 160 kB     |
| auth               | audit_log_entries                     | 336 kB     |
| auth               | instances                             | 16 kB      |
| auth               | schema_migrations                     | 24 kB      |
| public             | card_tag                              | 56 kB      |
| public             | users                                 | 32 kB      |
| public             | cards                                 | 144 kB     |
| public             | collections                           | 32 kB      |
| public             | tags                                  | 32 kB      |
| storage            | buckets                               | 24 kB      |
| storage            | migrations                            | 40 kB      |
| storage            | objects                               | 32 kB      |
| auth               | identities                            | 104 kB     |
| realtime           | schema_migrations                     | 24 kB      |
| realtime           | subscription                          | 56 kB      |
| auth               | users                                 | 176 kB     |
```

Does this help narrow down the possible cause?

UPDATE 1:

Ran the following queries:

```
vacuum verbose pg_statistic;
vacuum verbose pg_class;
```

Output:

```
vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_class"
launched 2 parallel vacuum workers for index cleanup (planned: 2)
"pg_class": found 0 removable, 358975 nonremovable row versions in 8160 out of 8160 pages
vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_statistic"
"pg_statistic": found 0 removable, 122120 nonremovable row versions in 5330 out of 5330 pages
vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_2619"
"pg_toast_2619": found 0 removable, 98 nonremovable row versions in 22 out of 22 pages
```

```sql
SELECT pg_stat_statements_reset();
SELECT pg_stat_reset();
```

The database size hasn't decreased. However, I had added two new rows into one of my tables and the size increased from 162 MB to now 163.67 MB.

UPDATE 2:

```sql
select count(*) from pg_class
```

| count |
| --- |
| 469 |

UPDATE 3:

Table schemas:

`cards`

```
| column_name   | data_type | character_maximum_length | column_default | is_nullable |
| ------------- | --------- | ------------------------ | -------------- | ----------- |
| id            | bigint    |                          |                | NO          |
| user_id       | uuid      |                          |                | NO          |
| excerpt       | text      |                          |                | YES         |
| note          | text      |                          |                | YES         |
| collection_id | bigint    |                          |                | YES         |
| created_at    | date      |                          | now()          | NO          |
| tags          | ARRAY     |                          |                | NO          |
| fts           | tsvector  |                          |                | YES         |
```

`tags`

```
| column_name | data_type | character_maximum_length | column_default | is_nullable |
| ----------- | --------- | ------------------------ | -------------- | ----------- |
| id          | bigint    |                          |                | NO          |
| user_id     | uuid      |                          |                | NO          |
| name        | text      |                          |                | NO          |
| colour      | character | 6                        |                | NO          |
```

`collections`

```
| column_name | data_type | character_maximum_length | column_default | is_nullable |
| ----------- | --------- | ------------------------ | -------------- | ----------- |
| id          | bigint    |                          |                | NO          |
| name        | text      |                          |                | NO          |
| link        | text      |                          |                | YES         |
| user_id     | uuid      |                          |                | NO          |
| author      | text      |                          |                | YES         |
```

`card_tag`

```
| column_name | data_type | character_maximum_length | column_default | is_nullable |
| ----------- | --------- | ------------------------ | -------------- | ----------- |
| card_id     | bigint    |                          |                | NO          |
| tag_id      | bigint    |                          |                | NO          |
| user_id     | uuid      |                          |                | NO          |
```

`users`

```
| column_name | data_type | character_maximum_length | column_default | is_nullable |
| ----------- | --------- | ------------------------ | -------------- | ----------- |
| id          | uuid      |                          |                | NO          |
| email       | text      |                          |                | YES         |
| customer_id | text      |                          |                | YES         |
```

UPDATE 4:
`fts` column in `cards` table is generated as:

```sql
ALTER TABLE cards
ADD COLUMN fts tsvector generated always as (to_tsvector('english', excerpt || ' ' || note)) stored;
```

`fts` is also indexed.

```sql
create index cards_fts on cards using gin (fts);
```

UPDATE 5:

```sql
vacuum verbose pg_class;
```

```
vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_class"
launched 1 parallel vacuum worker for index cleanup (planned: 1)
"pg_class": found 0 removable, 358987 nonremovable row versions in 8160 out of 8160 pages
```

```sql
select pg_column_size(to_tsvector('english', excerpt || ' ' || note)) from cards;
```

```
| pg_column_size |
| -------------- |
| 80             |
| 196            |
| 68             |
| 514            |
| 198            |
| 32             |
| 32             |
| 78             |
| 186            |
| 62             |
| 370            |
| 34             |
| 436            |
| 540            |
| 314            |
| 560            |
| 20             |
| 46             |
| 472            |
| 136            |
| 124            |
| 84             |
| 22             |
| 592            |
| 22             |
| 318            |
| 54             |
| 516            |
| 54             |
| 250            |
| 106            |
| 76             |
| 296            |
| 450            |
| 38             |
| 34             |
| 178            |
|                |
| 170            |
```

UPDATE 6:

```sql
select relname ,pg_stat_get_live_tuples(c.oid) AS live_tuples ,pg_stat_get_dead_tuples(c.oid) AS dead_tuples from pg_class c order by dead_tuples desc
```

```
| relname                                         | live_tuples | dead_tuples |
| ----------------------------------------------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| pg_class                                        | 469         | 358518      |
| pg_attribute                                    | 0           | 126         |
| pg_depend                                       | 0           | 10          |
| pg_type                                         | 0           | 7           |
| pg_shdepend                                     | 225         | 6           |
| users                                           | 1           | 4           |
| refresh_tokens                                  | 6           | 3           |
| card_tag                                        | 5           | 2           |
| pg_db_role_setting                              | 7           | 1           |
| cards                                           | 3           | 1           |
| pg_index                                        | 0           | 1           |
| identities                                      | 1           | 1           |
| pg_authid                                       | 18          | 1
```

UPDATE 7:

```sql
select pid, state, usename, query, query_start from pg_stat_activity where pid in ( select pid from pg_locks l join pg_class t on l.relation = t.oid and t.relkind = 'r' where t.relname in ('pg_class','cards', 'tags', 'collections', 'card_tag', 'users') );
```

```
| pid   | state  | usename        | query                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | query_start                   |
| ----- | ------ | -------------- | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | ----------------------------- |
| 79331 | active | supabase_admin | 
-- source: dashboard
-- user: 20248
-- date: 2022-04-08T15:02:13.664Z

select pid, state, usename, query, query_start from pg_stat_activity where pid in ( select pid from pg_locks l join pg_class t on l.relation = t.oid and t.relkind = 'r' where t.relname in ('pg_class','cards', 'tags', 'collections', 'card_tag', 'users') );
 | 2022-04-08 15:02:14.123713+00 |
```

```sql
select version()
```

| version |
| --- |
| PostgreSQL 13.3 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0, 64-bit |

Comment: Did you run a VACUUM FULL on both tables?

Comment: Have you tried just resetting all the statistical metadata? Does running the following commands decrease the size? "VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE); SELECT pg_stat_statements_reset(); SELECT pg_stat_reset();"

Comment: @FrankHeikens I ran VACUUM VERBOSE on both the tables and updated the question with its findings. Ran VACUUM FULL on pg_statistic, I'm facing query timeout erros on running it on pg_class. Will work on fixing this...

Comment: @Cninroh I ran those queries and updated the question. Unfortunately, the size has not decreased.

Comment: 1) Select from [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) and look for rows that have a `state` of 'idle in transaction' or 'idle in transaction  (aborted)'.  2) `select count(*) from pg_class` and add as update to question.

Comment: Looks like you have a roque process doing stuff it should not be allow to do. Kill every connection that you don't trust and make sure these user(-s) can't create new connections to your database.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Running the first query does not return any rows with said `state`. Although there are 4 rows with state 'idle'. I have updated the question with the second query

Comment: Look at the actual contents of pg_class.  An "empty" database should have about 400 entries for system objects.  Your has a lot more, but we don't know if they are real things or the remnants of obsolete things that can't be removed yet.

Comment: What are you storing the tables? Provide the table schema.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have updated the question. I think I started noticing the growth in size after adding the `fts` column in `cards` table. It is a generated column and is also indexed.

Comment: How is `fts` generated? I'm still trying to figure out: `"pg_class": found 0 removable, 358975 nonremovable row versions ...` , in particular the nonremovable rows. Same for pg_statistic.  Looks like something is holding those rows open. Have you had any issues, other then growth in size,  with the database lately? Can you and have you restarted the server?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have added another update. No I have not noticed any other issues. I restarted the server now but there is no change.
I'm using [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/api/client) on a node.js server to query the DB in production. I'm opening as well as closing the connection everytime. So that shouldn't cause this problem right?

Comment: Did you check the logfiles? And do you log all connections and at least all ddl-statements?

Comment: 1) After the restart did `vacuum verbose pg_class;` remove rows? 2) What does `select pg_column_size(to_tsvector('english', excerpt || ' ' || note)) from cards;` return?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Running that after restart does not remove any rows, unfortunately. I have updated the question with the results.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have access to logs for the past 7 days. What should I look for in there? All the connections seem to be routine (from Supabase where the database is hosted).

Comment: @DebabrataMondal Could you also check how big is fts? "select
    pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(fts))) as total_size,
    pg_size_pretty(avg(pg_column_size(fts))) as average_size,
    sum(pg_column_size(fts)) * 100.0 / pg_relation_size('cards') as percentage
from cards;"

Comment: @DebabrataMondal Could you also add the output of this query? "select
    relname
     ,pg_stat_get_live_tuples(c.oid) AS live_tuples
     ,pg_stat_get_dead_tuples(c.oid) AS dead_tuples
from pg_class c order by dead_tuples desc;"

Comment: @Cninroh I have updated the question. I only posted the first few rows that are returned. The ones that that are not shown here have 0 live and dead tuples...

Comment: @DebabrataMondal So it seems that the rows are indeed dead, but for some reason are not removed. I would start by checking, what active queries create locks: "select pid, state, usename, query, query_start
from pg_stat_activity
where pid in (
    select pid from pg_locks l
                        join pg_class t on l.relation = t.oid
        and t.relkind = 'r'
    where t.relname in ('pg_class','cards', 'tags', 'collections', 'card_tag', 'users')
);" and then kill those with: SELECT pg_terminate_backend(PID); and do VACUUM (FULL, ANALYZE, VERBOSE); (automatically will do the whole DB.)

Comment: @DebabrataMondal Since you are using Supabase, its not really a vanilla Postgres. Have you reached our to their support to verify, that this is not something specific to their platform? Reading trough all the suggestions and comments, I conclude that something is configured (most likely) in such a way, as to not permit you to clean the rows, if the above mentioned help does not create any effects. Is there maybe some cleanup/vacuum option from their Portal, that might allow you to do these maintenance activities with elevated permissions?

Comment: @DebabrataMondal I recreated your cards DB for demonstration purposes: "create table cards (id bigint not null, user_id uuid not null, excerpt text, note text, collection_id bigint, created_at date default now() not null, tag integer array not null);
INSERT INTO cards (id, user_id, excerpt, note, collection_id, tag)
SELECT i, gen_random_uuid(), 'excerpt text' || i::text, 'note text' || i::text, i, '{1}'
FROM generate_series(1, 300) AS t(i);" This whole DB is only 7MB in size.

Comment: @DebabrataMondal After we add fts: "alter table cards
    add column fts tsvector generated always as (to_tsvector('english', excerpt || ' ' || note)) stored; and index create index cards_fts on cards using gin (fts);" then whole DB is still only 8MB in size. (In both instances incl. pg_class). This is on Pg. 13.4. I also cannot reproduce the pg_class not vacuuming correctly, incl using autovacuum. Could you also post output of "select version()" to see what build you are running?

Comment: @Cninroh Thank you very much for the comments. I have updated the question with the query results. I'm not sure if it's safe to terminate that process (I'll email Supabase's support team for some more info). I checked the DB logs after running vacuum and I'm getting that weird error. Also, yes initially my database was around 10 MB. It started ballooning from there with very little addition of data.

Comment: @Cninroh Nevermind, I cannot reproduce the vacuum error now. Anyway I will email Supabase's support team.